# Is there any way to use chrome extension on iPad

Tags: ios, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would like to use chrome extension on iPad with google chrome.

Is there any way to use it?

I tried to install Orion which is 3rd party browser, but I could not use below extension、

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bambuser-one-to-one/fkhddgplfbdjopphepkohfgdkikfleai

best

I need to use Bambuser on iPad with google chrome browser.
not with Bambuser application

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

No. Google Chrome does not support Chrome extensions on iOS. That is only available for the desktop web browser.

If you use Safari (on your iPad), then you can install Safari extensions.
[https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-extensions-iphab0432bf6/ios#:~:text=View%20and%20add%20Safari%20extensions,then%20follow%20the%20onscreen%20instructions](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-extensions-iphab0432bf6/ios#:%7E:text=View%20and%20add%20Safari%20extensions,then%20follow%20the%20onscreen%20instructions).

Comment: Thank you for the imfomation, but I need to use Chrome...

Comment: You can feedback Google Chrome team at https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0

Answer (score 0):

you can use orion browser for iPad and iphone and you can also use it on your mac if you have and they sync also all your pasword and bookmark favorite website across all your apple devices i try it today and he work good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).